# Манипулирование элементами DOM модели с помощью jQuery

Tags: jquery, xml, html, dom

Чем отличается DOM модель созданная на основе HTML документа от DOM модели созданной на основе XML документа, с точки зрения jQuery? Есть какие-то принципиальные отличия или все идентично работает?

Comment: Просто кто-то утверждает, что DOM модель HTML и XML (SVG) абсолютно идентичны, кто-то утверждает обратное... А что думаете Вы по данному вопросу?

Comment: html допускает одиночные теги вила <br> в то время как в xml они обязаны быть вида <br/>. Это практическое различие, но как по стандарту надо смотреть. Но с точки зрения jQuery, я думаю, однохренственно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет никаких отличий. Разве что в случае HTML jquery предоставляет псевдо свойства и методы, такие как например .val() возвращает значение элемента формы.

Для работы с XML скажем из переменной просто напишите

```
$(xml).find(selector)
```

Ну и далее работайте на здоровье

Answer (score 3):

DOM - это объектная модель представления документа. HTML, XML, RSS и т.п. - это различные языки, которые могут использоваться для представления документа. DOM (модель документа), созданная на основе разных языков, отличается набором используемых объектов. jQuery заточен под использование DOM созданных на основе HTML, для него отличные объекты или свойства объектов, используемые вне HTML могут быть (и скорее всего будут) непонятны.